# Scala environment ${USER} in application.conf

Tags: scala, playframework

I read the book titled "Play for Scala" written in 2013 and see an code example like this one:

inside application.conf file:

```
environment.user = ${USER}
```

And inside some template file:

```
@()(implicit messages: Messages)
@import java.util.Date
@import play.api.Play.current

<footer>
    lang = @messages.lang.code
    user = @current.configuration.getString("environment.user")    // <<--- this line
    date = @(new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))
</footer>
```

And after running the example I get an error:

**application.conf @ file:/C:/Users/Maciek/IdeaProjects/play-scala/target/scala-2.11/classes/application.conf: 18: Could not resolve substitution to a value: ${USER}**

I would like to ask what is ${USER} environment variable, where does it come from?
and why does it not work?

I know that in the book play version is 2.1 and mine is 2.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more of an OS question. On Linux/Unix you usually have `$USER` defined as the current user (who is running shell or your app).
To check the value in `bash` do:

```
# echo $USER
yourname
```

In Windows you can check it from `cmd` with:

```
C:\> echo %USER%
%USER%
```

As you can see it's not defined on my machine. Perhaps you are using Windows and getting the same error. You can set `USER` environment variable in your OS for it to be able to find the value or provide a fallback value in your conf.

Comment: I thought so, that it is USER system environment variable. I tried do same as you: echo %USER% but MacOSX and Windows displayed %USER% so i was confused.. thanks!

Comment: so then, using ${} in application.conf is the way to use OS environment variables?

Comment: on Mac you should use this command: `echo $USER` since it's Unix. Yes `${}` accesses an environment variable. If you want to look deeper into the awesome Typesafe Config library take a look at the docs here: https://github.com/typesafehub/config. Cheers