# Reading configuration files from unit tests

Tags: scala, scalatest, typesafe-config

I have a very simply project.

build.sbt:

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.13.5"

lazy val testSettings = Seq(
  Test / javaOptions += "-Dconfig.resource=/test.conf"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.3" % Test, 
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.4.1"
)
```

Two configuration files under resources folder:

application.conf

```
some-value = "value from application.conf file"
```

test.conf

```
some-value = "value from test.conf file"
```

And only 1 spec test class:

SomeTestSpec:

```scala
class SomeTestSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers {
  val config: Config = ConfigFactory.load()

  "some test" should "read and print from test.conf" in {
    val value = config.getString("some-value")
    println(s"value of some-value = $value")

    value shouldBe "value from test.conf file"
  }
}
```

When I run the test if fails:

```
"value from [application].conf file" was not equal to "value from [test].conf file"
ScalaTestFailureLocation: SomeTestSpec at (SomeTestSpec.scala:12)
Expected :"value from [test].conf file"
Actual   :"value from [application].conf file"
```

Why the spec is reading the file `application.conf` instead of `test.conf`? Is something wrong in the build.sbt?:

```
lazy val testSettings = Seq(
  Test / javaOptions += "-Dconfig.resource=/test.conf"
)
```

Comment: Try removing the whole `testSettings` thing and just leaving this `Test / javaOptions += "-Dconfig.resource=/test.conf"` at top level.

Comment: I did that but I got the same result, the spec is still reading from application.conf instead of test.conf ...

Comment: What about moving `test.conf` to `src/test/resources/application.conf`?

Comment: Yes, it worked. But still my question is what is this line for `Test / javaOptions += "-Dconfig.resource=/test.conf"` ?? Because the spec is reading from application.conf (in `src/test/resources/application.conf`) instead of `test.conf` (`-Dconfig.resource=/test.conf`)

Comment: No in that case that line won't be needed at all, no idea why it didn't work or if it shouldn't have worked at all.

Comment: If you're meant to just read the config for other use and not testing the "read config from resource" then I'd recommend you put the config string in your scala source & parse that String. That'll do away with any of classpath stuff & limit your configuration to limited scope (say you have to have different tests referring to slightly different config file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to place `application.conf` into `src/main/resources/` for regular use and into `src/test/resources/` for testing. You'll have 2 conf files with different values in test. If you don't need to change config for test you can simply keep one conf file in `main`.

You don't have to override the file explicitly with `-Dconfig.resource` or `-Dconfig.file` for your tests because loading resources from class path will work as you expect out of the box and your test config will be used. `-D` option is mostly used at runtime to provide external configuration or in some complex build scenarios.

If you use `-Dconfig.resource` or `-Dconfig.file` pay attention to the path. `config.resource` is just a filename, i.e. `application.conf` which will be loaded as resource while `config.file` is an absolute or relative file path.

If you are making a library you can get fancy with `reference.conf` file having default values and `application.conf` overriding them. This could also work in your scenario but would be more confusing because that's not the purpose or reference file.

For the purposes of testing just use 2 `application.conf` files.

Additionally, here are some options to override config at runtime:

[Overriding multiple config values in Typesafe config when using an uberjar to deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966621/overriding-multiple-config-values-in-typesafe-config-when-using-an-uberjar-to-de).

[Overriding configuration with environment variables in typesafe config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197406/overriding-configuration-with-environment-variables-in-typesafe-config/38239969#38239969)

[Scala environment ${USER} in application.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412944/scala-environment-user-in-application-conf/32414281#32414281)

More info here: https://github.com/lightbend/config#standard-behavior

Comment: Thank you very much, that clarify how configuration files are being read. Now some things are making sense to me.

Comment: Thank you very much, that clarify how configuration files are being read. Now some things are making sense to me.